# Using a bat file to reconnect network drives

Tags: windows, networking, batch-file

I'm trying to update a company's servers and they have all the computers connecting to specific network drives at login.  I'm trying to find the location of the `bat` file.  I want to say they all use the same `bat` file and it's located on the server somewhere.  Is that possible or do all the computers have their own `bat` file?

Either way what would the most common location for that file be?

Comment: If this isn't a real question how come it got a real answer that solved the issue?  Also, why would you close it after it was already answered and marked as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must look on your Active Directory server... in the SYSVOL

If you have more than one or not sure where your AD is, try the following:

Goto to RUN and type:

> "%LOGONSERVER%\SYSVOL"

or from a cmd prompt type

> echo %LOGONSERVER%

Otherwise the path would be like this:

> \\Servername\SYSVOL\yourdomain.local\scripts